# task jade not found when running grunt

Tags: gruntjs, pug

When I run grunt with the following Gruntfile, I get the error Warning: task "jade" not found. what exactly could be wrong here?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

      jade: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                client: false,
                pretty: true
            },
            files: [ {
              cwd: "app/views",
              src: "**/*.jade",
              dest: "build/templates",
              expand: true,
              ext: ".html"
            } ]
        }
    }   
    });

   grunt.registerTask('default','Convert Jade templates into html templates',
                  ['jade','watch']);
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to load grunt jade task. The same as yo are adding grunt-contrib-watch

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jade');
```

This should works.